# Change shell in shell script when running in sudo

Tags: zsh

My simple shell script looks like this

test.sh

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo $SHELL
```

When I run command `sh test.sh`, result is `/bin/zsh`.

And when I run command `sudo sh test.sh`, result is `/bin/bash`.

I want to run this script with `sudo` and need the shell to be `zsh`. Can anyone help?

Comment: `sudo /bin/zsh test.sh` ?

Comment: In my case `zsh` is located at  `/usr/bin/zsh`. Output for above code with `#!/usr/bin/zsh` is `#!/usr/bin/zsh`. You might check this.

Comment: As a deleted answer points out, `$SHELL` isn't the current shell. It's your login shell.

Comment: If you need to *execute* the script with `zsh`, then don't use `sh`. Either `sudo /bin/zsh test.sh` or make the script executable (`chmod +x test.sh`) and execute it with `sudo ./test.sh`.

Comment: /bin/zsh test.sh won't make any sense as script should take the shell mentioned in the script. Well after few hit & try, I figured out that I didn't had zsh set to default for superuser. After doing that, my script took zsh in sudo mode too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#!/bin/zsh` tells the OS that when your script is started as an *executable,* it should use `zsh` to run it. This happens *only* when you have done `chmod a+x test` and then run your script by typing

```sh
test.sh
```

When you instead do

```sh
sh test.sh
```

then you are passing your script directly to `sh` and the shebang is ignored.

---

`echo $SHELL` does *not* print the current shell, but just the current user's *login* shell. For you, that's apparently `zsh`, but for the super user, that's apparently `bash`. Again, though, that says absolutely nothing about the shell that is running your script.

---

To run your script with `sudo` in `zsh`, just do

```sh
sudo test.zsh
```

Alternatively, no matter what shebang you have in the file, you can always force the script to run in `zsh` by doing

```sh
sudo zsh test.zsh
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks